# Where does WHM place .pem files for SSL

Tags: php, ssl, mysqli, whm

I'm setting up SSL on my website, and I can't figure out where the .pem files are, or how to get them if I don't have them. I generated the certificate and signing request with WHM, "issued" the certificate with namecheap's interface with comodo, and then installed the certificate with whm, via copy and paste. Now I'm looking to set up `mysqli_ssl_set()`.

I originally tried to use the files located in /etc/ssl, which also contains a shortcut file to etc/pki/tls/certs. After messing around with these, I couldn't get them to work(`mysqli_ssl_set()` keeps coming up as a boolean). The files I was using were .key and .crt files, and w3schools page on `mysqli_ssl_set()` specifies .pem files. So, I looked up .pem files, and found that they are plaintext. So then I tried creating my own, via copy and paste. This also gave the same error.

So, where are the .pem files placed by WHM generally? Or, if they are not generated by WHM, how can I best resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They were placed in etc/ssl/private. For some reason, in FileZilla .pem files look like links to folders, which was off-putting.